# How to get hash values from a multiple check_box in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a N to M relationship between some multiples elements at my app. So, I want to delete all those relationships on a form. To do that, Im including a check_box at my form, and want to pass the N.id and the M.id to my controller.

Everything is being passed ok to my controller. But I got an error when trying to retrieve those values.

```
    <% duplicated.each do |element|%>
      <tr id="row_user_<%=element["product_lot"].id%>">
        <td><%= check_box_tag "product_lots[]", {:bol_id => element["bill_of_lading"].id, :product_lot_id => element["product_lot"].id} %>
```

And in my controller I got:

```
selected_product_lots = params[:product_lots]

selected_product_lots.each do |element|
  logger.debug("#{element[:bol_id]}")
end
```

If I do a print on my params[:product_lots] I have:

```
["{:bol_id=>3086, :product_lot_id=>6021}"]
```

So, I want to know how can I get the bol_id and the product_id from each element. At the moment, im getting a error when I try to do this:

```
#{element[:bol_id]}"


no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the api of [`check_box_tag`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-check_box_tag):

```
check_box_tag(name, value = "1", checked = false, options = {})
```

- The first argument is the name: what the value is stored under, and this usually shows up in params
- The second argument is the value, and this gets stringified in order to make the html tag.
- Third is the beginning checked state
- Finally is the options

So since you are passing an object to value, rails is calling `.to_s` on that object in order to create the html tag. That is why you are getting the `no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer` error, because you are calling [`[…]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) on a string, which returns the nth character of the string. It's not the best error message, unfortunately, because it doesn't mention that you are accessing a string, not a hash, and it would be the same error message for an array as well. What you probably want is to serialize the value so that you can unserialize it later:

- Try calling `.to_json` on the second argument. This should change your value in `params[:product_lots]` to `['{"bol_id": 3086, "product_lot_id": 6021}']`.
- Notice that this is still a string, so you need to deserialize it (although there is a chance rails could automatically deserialize this, depending on configuration and filters, etc.).
- try `params[:product_lots].map!{|data| JSON.parse(data, object_class: HashWithIndifferentAccess)}`. This should now give you an array of hashes ([with indifferent access](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html), so you can use symbol keys). (See also [`Json::parse`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-parse))
- you can now get the values you wish
- consider moving this into a helper, before action/filter, etc., to be able to use it multiple times, potentially for multiple parameters

Comment: What a answer. Perfect. Thanks Garret. Make my day